# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am working on hand-rolling a user authentication system for fun.  I've created two different models, a `UserAccount` and `UserCredential` the idea being that credentials such as email, username, profile pic, etc are separate from the actual account.

In order to create a `UserCredential` when a `UserAccount` is created I am using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.  I am running into some issues saving the `UserCredential` when the `UserAccount` saves.

Migration:

```
  create_table :user_accounts, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.references :user_credentials
      ...
    end

    add_reference :user_credentials, :user_account, type: :uuid, null: false, foreign_key: true
```

`user_account.rb`

```
  has_one :user_credential, inverse_of: :user_account, dependent: :destroy
  ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_credential
  validates_associated :user_credential
```

`user_credential.rb`

```
class UserCredential < ApplicationRecord
  validates :email, uniqueness: true

  belongs_to :user_account, inverse_of: :user_credential
  validates_presence_of :user_account
```

`accounts_controller.rb`

```
  def new
    @user = UserAccount.new
  end

  def create
    @user = UserAccount.create!(user_params)
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user_account).permit(user_credentials: [:email])
    # I'm not sure if `user_credential` should be plural here or not?

  end
```

`_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_with model: @user, local: true do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :user_credentials do |u| %>
    <div class="form-control">
      <%= u.label :email %>
      <%= u.email_field :email %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

Two small things I've noticed:

1. if I change the params and the `fields_for` to `user_credential` (removing the plural) the email field disappears.
2. If I keep the params as is I get this exception:  `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'user_credentials' for UserAccount.):`

I've seen people recommending adding a `@user.user_credential.build()` to the new method but doing that just gives me a `nil:NilClass` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to change `user_credentials` to `user_credentials_attributes`

```rb
 def user_params
    params.require(:user_account).permit(user_credentials_attributes: [:email])
 end
```

When nested attributes are submitted through a form, the `_attributes` tag is appended for the nested attributes parent.

Comment: That did the trick, I did not realize the importance of `_attributes`.